# Oracle Universal Installer stops after launch (Oracle Forms and Reports 12.2.1.4)

Tags: windows, oracle, oracleforms

i try to install Oracle Forms and Reports 12.2.1.4, but everytime I run setup.fmw.12.2.1.4.0_fr_win64.exe file Oracle Universal Installer window shows up for a moment with communicate "Preparing the installer...". After that it dissappears and shows again with another communicate: "Cleaning up...". After this communicate, the installer window turns off and there are no other steps.

Screens below

[first communicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XJBX.png)

[second communicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zl69F.png)

Did anybody have this problem also? My JAVA_HOME is set as C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_241 and PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin.

Here's also -debug log below

```
m_szTempDirectory: C:\Windows\Temp
Extract to C:\Windows\Temp\sfxCD9A.tmp
Extracting sfx.ini from D:\setup_fmw_12.2.1.4.0_fr_win64.exe to C:\Windows\Temp\sfxCD9A.tmp
Wiz_SingleEntryUnzip (extractAutorun) return code: 0
Total uncompressed size: 2447428290
m_szTempDirectory: C:\Windows\Temp
Extract to same C:\Windows\Temp\sfxCD9A.tmp
Extracting installer files
Wiz_SingleEntryUnzip() result: 0
Total disks: 1 (1)
Finished extracting Disk1
Using version 1.8.0.211.12 of component Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.jre
Jar list: Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.jre\1.8.0.211.12\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar
New command: oracle.jre\.\jdk\jre\bin\java.exe  -jar install/modules/ora-launcher.jar
Unzipping Java jars Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.jre\1.8.0.211.12\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar to oracle.jre
Getting size of Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.jre\1.8.0.211.12\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar
Size of Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.jre\1.8.0.211.12\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar: 201205655
Checking space for Java components in C:\Windows\Temp
Unzipping Java jars: Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.jre\1.8.0.211.12\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar
Unzipping Disk1\stage\Components\oracle.jre\1.8.0.211.12\DataFiles\filegroup1.jar
Launch command length: 278
Launch command: "C:\Windows\Temp\sfxCD9A.tmp\oracle.jre\jdk\jre\bin\java.exe" "-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Windows\Temp" "-Dsfx.installer.launcher.home=D:\" "-Dsfx.extract.path=C:\Windows\Temp\sfxCD9A.tmp" "-Dsfx.exe=D:\setup_fmw_12.2.1.4.0_fr_win64.exe"  -jar install/modules/ora-launcher.jar "-debug"
cmdLine: "C:\Windows\Temp\sfxCD9A.tmp\oracle.jre\jdk\jre\bin\java.exe" "-Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Windows\Temp" "-Dsfx.installer.launcher.home=D:\" "-Dsfx.extract.path=C:\Windows\Temp\sfxCD9A.tmp" "-Dsfx.exe=D:\setup_fmw_12.2.1.4.0_fr_win64.exe"  -jar install/modules/ora-launcher.jar "-debug"
Command successfully started; waiting for completion
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server.

    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
dwExitCode: 1
myspawn() result: 1
Press any key to exit
```

Comment: Do you run installer as Admin? Does installation folder have any space characters (they are not permitted). Clean your TEMP folder, esp. `%TEMP%\deinstall*`, `%TEMP%\OraInstall*` and `%TEMP%\CVU*`

Comment: Yes I run it as Admin. I did what you said, cleaned whole Temp folder, run installer and the problem is still the same.

Comment: Just downloaded installed without any problem.Look for launcher log file.It runs prechecks just minimum cpu,read and write access to registry,enough ram,swap and temp space if successful leads to installation screen.

Comment: I checked logs in inventory, but there was nothing. Only logs from my previous WebLogic instalation. I'm worring that all I got is that debug log from cmd what I attached

Answer (score 0):

To be clear, you need to start the installer using an elevated shell.  This is not the same as being a member of the Windows "Administrator" group.  Right-click on the exe and click on "Run as administrator".

Comment: Well, as i said it before - i did that, and it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running setup.exe, try execute \install\oui.exe -debug